# CakePHP 3 saving associated data across 2 tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp, save, associations, cakephp-3.0

Update: Removed 0 from form input and the s from session, while also changing the relationship from Booking hasMany Sessions to Booking hasOne Session.

So I have 4 tables relevant to this:

- Bookings (where the form with the input fields is from)
- Sessions (linked to Bookings)
- Sessionplayers_sessions (joined table between Sessionplayers & Sessions)
- Sessionplayers

When using my form, I attempt to save across Bookings, Sessions & Sessionplayer_sessions. The form input below is the only relevant field for Sessionplayer_sessions:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('session.sessionplayers._ids', ['type' => 'select', 'options'=>'','multiple']); ?>
```

The options while in the form input show as blank, come from a dual list jQuery script which allows for the selection of multiple items.

However, when I attempt to save, nothing from the above input is actually posted into the Sessionplayer_sessions table, while everything in Bookings & Sessions is successfully posted.

In the Controller, this is what the newEntity & patchEntity sections look like:

```
$booking = $this->Bookings->newEntity($this->request->data(),[
        'associated'=>[
          'Sessions' => ['associated' => ['Guestengineers', 'Sessionplayers']]
      ]]);
      if($this->request->is('post')){
        $data = $this->request->data;
        $booking = $this->Bookings->patchEntity($booking, $data, [
          'associated'=>[
            'Sessions' => ['associated' => ['Guestengineers', 'Sessionplayers']]
          ]
        ]);
```

And the respective models of both the Sessions and Sessionplayers tables:

Sessions:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('sessions');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongstoMany('Sessionplayers', [
        'foreignKey' => 'session_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'sessionplayer_id',
        'joinTable' => 'Sessionplayers_sessions'
    ]);
}
```

Sessionplayers:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('sessionplayers');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongstoMany('Sessions', [
        'foreignKey' => 'sessionplayer_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'session_id',
        'joinTable' => 'Sessionplayers_sessions'
    ]);
}
```

**Results:**

Upon updating the form input and the relationship between the Bookings & Sessions table and resubmitting:

In the post data, sessionplayers is now an array inside the session array. Inside the sessionplayers array is a single attribute: _ids, with the value referencing the id of the first sessionplayer that was selected in the form input's multiple select - for example, if I selected the 3rd sessionplayer and the 4th sessionplayer, _ids = 3. However, in the database itself, while the bookings and sessions table data was able to be successfully inserted, sessionplayers_session's table did not.

Basically: Request data arrays are as follows: Session (array) -> Sessionplayers (array) -> _ids = 3.

In the SQL log, only two Insert Into SQL statements occurred, one for Bookings and one for Sessions. Sessionplayers_sessions had no such insert.

Comment: The `0` looks misplaced. The magic `_ids` key is supposed to be connected directly to the association property name. Also, please always try to do a little debugging, as questions that are basically just "_doesn't work_" are usually considered offtopic. In your case checking what exactly the request data and the patched entity looks like in your controller is probably most relevant.

Comment: Oh I did that. Upon submitting, in Request, the join table's attributes weren't present in the post data. I also tried the Cookbook's through option for the many to many association, but there was no difference. When you say the 0 is misplaced, where is 0 normally meant to go relative to associated tables?

Comment: I didn't just mean to say _do some debugging_, but especially ment that the results should be in your question. I'd say the `0` shouldn't be there at all in your case, the `_ids` key should be directly connected to `sessionplayers`. Check the examples in the docs: **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-belongstomany-data**

Comment: Updated my post with the results after removing the 0 and changing the relationship between the bookings and sessions table.

Comment: I think I managed to fix it - I added an array [] right after _ids, and they seem to have saved properly, although I did get several warnings upon saving.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I managed to fix it after removing the 0 from the form input and changing the relationship from OneToMany to OneToOne, by adding in [] to represent that there could be several items being selected.